# Execute java in shell and wait until i get the return code

Tags: java, shell, return-value

I am now executing java a java program like this:

```
package com.test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        execute();
    }

    public static String  execute(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "a";
    }
}
```

I want to execute the Test.execute() method in linux shell script, wait until the method return and get return code . but the return of main() method is void , so  what Can I do the get a return code or return msg from it ?

Any suggestions?

---

I find a solution:

```
package com.test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
          execute();
    }

    public static String  execute(){
        try {
            System.out.println("sleeping");;
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exit(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "a";
    }
}
```

And then my shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp test.jar com.test.Test
echo "The return code of the java application is $?"
```

I can get the value n which is in  `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(n)`;

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: What "return code"? You're not setting any above.

Comment: What shell? bash? Windows cmd?

Comment: It is conventional to call `System.exit()` instead of `Runtime.getRunTime().exit()` please check the docs here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit-int-.

Answer (score 0):

The shell script would have to call `java  com.test.Test`. And this will call the main method which inturn is currently calling execute.
From a shell script you would have to start a JVM and a JVM always starts with a Main method.
As for the return code, you can access it using the `$?` shell variable.
So basically your shell script would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp . com.test.Test
echo "The return code of the java application is $?"
```

Also you need to specify the classpath where all you relevant classes reside. In the above example I am putting in the current dir as the classpath.

The JVM will terminate with a exit code of 0 on completion of all non-daemon threads. If you want to return a specific exit code in case of an error you can use `System.exit(<codehere>)`. Please note that calling `System.exit()` will cause the JVM to shutdown even if there are other non-daemon threads that are running.

Edit:
Added "-cp ." to the command based on the comments.
Added some exit code details

Comment: $? hold the status of previous command. in your case it'll keep the return value.

Comment: keep the return value ? but the java main() method's return value should be void.So what can I do?

Comment: And how will JVM know about classpath?

Answer (score 0):

First change the signature of `main` method in your code example:

`public static void main()` to  `public static void main(String[] args)`

Then instead of just calling the `execute` method from `main`, try to print the result using `System.out.println` :

```
System.out.println(execute());
```

and then in linux shell you can use following to get the return values:

```
> set out   = `java com.test.Test`
> echo $out
```